# How to preserve Proximo IP address when migrating Heroku app to another region

Tags: heroku, proximo

Simply speaking, I need to delete and re-create my Heroku app. If I add Proximo addon to a new app and set my old PROXIMO_URL env var there

```
PROXIMO_URL: http://proxy:...@proxy-....proximo.io
```

Will it work as expected? Will my new app get the old proxy IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IP address of your proxy unfortunately cannot be preserved between applications due to limitations of the Heroku addon system.

This is doubly true across regions, unless you would want to use a proxy in a different region which seems unlikely.

The best bet for you would probably be to go ahead and create the app in the other region and add Proximo to it. You could then get the new IP address whitelisted wherever necessary.